# Within New Relic I am not able to see all of my tagged applications, WHY?

Tags: newrelic

When i am in New Relic APM section viewing all of our company's apps, I notice across different environments that some apps do not show up. Has anyone experienced this before? if so what was the resolution.

And yes I have...
made sure the app is tagged properly within the config file
waited a while for New Relic to pick up on the app
and New Relic is installed on the server where the app is running

Answer (score 0):

This happens because New Relic's .Net agent cannot "hook" into applications that are not .Net 2.0 - 4.x, including .Net Core. This can be determined easily by knowing your application (had a dumb moment not knowing my app) or looking at the IIS Manager and looking under the CLR column